# Extracting only the JSON object from a POST request

Tags: react-native, axios, network-programming

I am using React Native and Axios to make a post request to an API. When I do console log res, I get this for data. "data": "
**Notice**:  Undefined index: on line **11**
{"id":"l\/R98123JFAS920sdjf"}",

I did not make the API, so I am not sure why it does that, but it returns a bunch of HTML looking code along with the id. The only thing I really want is the id, but I cannot use JSON.parse because of the "<". Does anyone have an idea on how I can just get the id from this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: `AXIOS.post("?location=" + "asdaasdads")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res.data");
        if (res.status == 200) {
          setShowPublish(true);
          setPublishedURL(res.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });`